# Slow Wifi download speed on 5GHZ but fast on 2.4GHz (upload is the same)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have have a problem with this wireless USB stick : [Netis wf2190](http://www.netis-systems.com/Home/detail/id/96.html) that is based on the Realtek 8812AU Chip. [The download is really slow on 5GHZ](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/6532245460) while [really fast on 2.4GHZ](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/6533353708) (it reaches 100Mbps that is for what I pay for).

I have the latest drivers installed (Realtek 8812AU Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB NIC) . The distance between my [FRITZ!Box 7490](https://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-7490/) modem and the adapter is about 3 meters, no walls in between. Also my modem has the latest firmware (06.83)

[image: Realtek Driver]

I have tried changing the modem channel but it was the same. Eventually I just let it on Auto.

[image: Wlan Modem]

I have no idea what can it be. Any Ideas? Thanks

Edit: Just to add that my other devices can (phone, tv, tablet) use the 5GHz net at full speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have *fix it* changing the standard mode from **802.11n+ac** to **802.11n+a**

I hope this helps other people.

Comment: This brings minimal advantage to me. 2.4 GHZ is still way better, but at least it helps a bit. 2 weeks of struggle... just to find out, that the fritzbox seems to have a bug, wtf. PS: I have EXACTLY the symptoms you describe.

Comment: @codepleb Just to comment. When I use 2.4GHz to play games (with Steam Link) it is imposible to play without a noticeable lag. This does not happens with 5GHz.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel Ethernet drivers are not related to your wifi adapter. They might be for your wired connection.

Download and install the latest drivers for your wireless adapter. They are found at the same site you already linked to:

http://www.netis-systems.com/Suppory/de_details/id/1/de/96.html

If that doesn't work, make sure your wireless router has the latest firmware installed, and also try changing the wireless channel for 5Ghz.

Comment: That is the driver I had. I copied/pasted the wrong driver name in my post sorry. I have fix it and added more info like my modem model (that has the latest firmware) I have tried all the available channels and eventually I just let it on AutoChannel.

Comment: It may just be a bad network adapter. Can you replace it or try it on another computer? Also, if 2.4Ghz works good then wouldn't it be suitable to just use 2.4Ghz?